# Getting all strings in a lua script

Tags: string, lua

I'm trying to encode some strings in my lua script, and since that I have a lua script with over 200k characters, encrypting each string query in the script with a function such as this example below

```
local string   =    "stackoverflow"
local string   =   [[stackoverflow]]
local string   = [==[stackoverflow]==]
local string   =    'stackoverflow'
```

to

```
local string=decode("jkrtbfmviwcfn",519211)
```

Trying to provide all above results to thread through a gsub and have the gsub encode the string text with a random offset number.

So far, I was only capable of gsubbing full quotation marks through.

```
function encode(x,offset,a)
    for char in string.gmatch(x, "%a") do
        local encrypted = string.byte(char) + offset
        while encrypted > 122 do
            encrypted = encrypted - 26
        end
        while encrypted < 97 do
            encrypted = encrypted + 26
        end
        a[#a+1] = string.char(encrypted)
    end
    return table.concat(a) 
end
luacode=[==[thatstring.Value="Encryptme!" testvalue.Value=[[string with
a linebreak]] string.Text="STOP!"]==]
luacode=luacode:gsub([=["(.-)"]=],function(s)
    print("Caught "..s)
    local offset=math.random(1,4)
    local encoded=encode(s,offset,{})
    return [[decode("]]..encoded..[[",]]..offset..[[)]]
end)
print("\n"..luacode)
```

With its output being

```
Caught Encryptme!
Caught STOP!

thatstring.Value=decode("crgvctxqi",4) testvalue.Value=[[string with
a linebreak]] string.Text=decode("opkl",2)
```

Any better solutions?

Comment: I'm curious: why do you want to do that? Is this an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Processing strings in Lua source robustly needs some sort of lexical analysis. Try my [ltokenp](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html#ltokenp).

Comment: I'm wanting some form of string text encryption to prevent people who have my source code to easily remove my credits. However, experienced users probably would work around my 200k character script to add their own credits.

Comment: @Nickoplier From the moment you give source code, it's very simple for one to trace the execution of the script, find at which point your encrypted credits are printed and replace them with their own non-encrypted ones.  Or, am I missing something?

Comment: That's why I wanted to have another lua script go through the entire script and encrypt the string with a random offset number. I would rather make it difficult to find where the credits are placed, than have people easily *ctrl-f* and replace text.

Comment: @Nickoplier You missed the point I was making.  The actual encrypted-strings script can be traced (as in executed step by step) to find at which point the credits are printed.  One doesn't need to know what the encrypted message looks like.  For example, once your print(decode('blah-blah-encrypted',31212)) which will actually print your credits is run it is enough for someone to spot it and replace it with print('My credits') instead bypassing your whole scheme.  Do you see what I'm saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local function strings_and_comments(lua_code, callback)
   -- lua_code must be valid Lua code (an error may be raised on syntax error)
   -- callback will be invoked as callback(object_type, value, start_pos, end_pos)
   --    callback("comment", comment_text, start_pos, end_pos)  -- for comments
   --    callback("string", string_value, start_pos, end_pos)   -- for string literals
   local objects = {}  -- possible comments and string literals in the code
   -- search for all start positions of comments (with false positives)
   for pos, br1, eq, br2 in lua_code:gmatch"()%-%-(%-*%[?)(=*)(%[?)" do
      table.insert(objects, {start_pos = pos,
         terminator = br1 == "[" and br2 == "[" and "]"..eq.."]" or "\n"})
   end
   -- search for all start positions of string literals (with false positives)
   for pos, eq in lua_code:gmatch"()%[(=*)%[[%[=]*" do
      table.insert(objects, {is_string = true, start_pos = pos,
         terminator = "]"..eq.."]"})
   end
   for pos, quote in lua_code:gmatch"()(['\"])" do
      table.insert(objects, {is_string = true, start_pos = pos, quote = quote})
   end
   table.sort(objects, function(a, b) return a.start_pos < b.start_pos end)
   local end_pos = 0
   for _, object in ipairs(objects) do
      local start_pos, ok, symbol = object.start_pos
      if start_pos > end_pos then
         if object.terminator == "\n" then
            end_pos = lua_code:find("\n", start_pos + 1, true) or #lua_code
            -- exclude last spaces and newline
            while lua_code:sub(end_pos, end_pos):match"%s" do
               end_pos = end_pos - 1
            end
         elseif object.terminator then
            ok, end_pos = lua_code:find(object.terminator, start_pos + 1, true)
            assert(ok, "Not a valid Lua code")
         else
            end_pos = start_pos
            repeat
               ok, end_pos, symbol = lua_code:find("(\\?.)", end_pos + 1)
               assert(ok, "Not a valid Lua code")
            until symbol == object.quote
         end
         local value = lua_code:sub(start_pos, end_pos):gsub("^%-*%s*", "")
         if object.terminator ~= "\n" then
            value = assert((loadstring or load)("return "..value))()
         end
         callback(object.is_string and "string" or "comment", value, start_pos, end_pos)
      end
   end
end

local inv256

local function encode(str)
   local seed = math.random(0x7FFFFFFF)
   local result = '",'..seed..'))'
   if not inv256 then
      inv256 = {}
      for M = 0, 127 do
         local inv = -1
         repeat inv = inv + 2
         until inv * (2*M + 1) % 256 == 1
         inv256[M] = inv
      end
   end
   repeat
      seed = seed * 3
   until seed > 2^43
   local K = 8186484168865098 + seed
   result = '(decode("'..str:gsub('.',
      function(m)
         local L = K % 274877906944   -- 2^38
         local H = (K - L) / 274877906944
         local M = H % 128
         m = m:byte()
         local c = (m * inv256[M] - (H - M) / 128) % 256
         K = L * 21271 + H + c + m
         return ('%02x'):format(c)
      end
   )..result
   return result
end

function hide_strings_in_lua_code(lua_code)
   local text = { [[
local function decode(str, seed)
   repeat
      seed = seed * 3
   until seed > 2^43
   local K = 8186484168865098 + seed
   return (str:gsub('%x%x',
      function(c)
         local L = K % 274877906944   -- 2^38
         local H = (K - L) / 274877906944
         local M = H % 128
         c = tonumber(c, 16)
         local m = (c + (H - M) / 128) * (2*M + 1) % 256
         K = L * 21271 + H + c + m
         return string.char(m)
      end
   ))
end
]] }
   local pos = 1
   strings_and_comments(lua_code,
      function (object_type, value, start_pos, end_pos)
         if object_type == "string" then
            table.insert(text, lua_code:sub(pos, start_pos - 1))
            table.insert(text, encode(value))
            pos = end_pos + 1
         end
      end)
   table.insert(text, lua_code:sub(pos))
   return table.concat(text)
end
```

**Usage:**

```
math.randomseed(os.time())

-- This is the program to be converted
local luacode = [===[
print"Hello world!"
print[[string with
a linebreak]]
local str1 =    "stackoverflow"
local str2 =   [[stackoverflow]]
local str3 = [==[stackoverflow]==]
local str4 =    'stackoverflow'
print(str1)
print(str2)
print(str3)
print(str4)
]===]

-- Conversion
print(hide_strings_in_lua_code(luacode))
```

**Output** (converted program)

```
local function decode(str, seed)
   repeat
      seed = seed * 3
   until seed > 2^43
   local K = 8186484168865098 + seed
   return (str:gsub('%x%x',
      function(c)
         local L = K % 274877906944   -- 2^38
         local H = (K - L) / 274877906944
         local M = H % 128
         c = tonumber(c, 16)
         local m = (c + (H - M) / 128) * (2*M + 1) % 256
         K = L * 21271 + H + c + m
         return string.char(m)
      end
   ))
end
print(decode("ef869b23b69b7fbc7f89bbe7",2686976))
print(decode("c2dc20f7061c452db49302f8a1d9317aad1009711e0984",1210253312))
local str1 =    (decode("84854df4599affe9c894060431",415105024))
local str2 =   (decode("a5d7db792f0b514417827f34e3",1736704000))
local str3 = (decode("6a61bcf9fd6f403ed1b4846e58",1256259584))
local str4 =    (decode("cad56d9dea239514aca9c8b8e0",1030488064))
print(str1)
print(str2)
print(str3)
print(str4)
```

**Output of output** (output produced by the converted program)

```
Hello world!
string with
a linebreak
stackoverflow
stackoverflow
stackoverflow
stackoverflow
```