# Is there some easy to locate all string literals in a Lua file?

Tags: string, lua

In my project, I find it very useful if there's a way to locate all string literals in a Lua file, because my team requires that every string literal containing any non-English character must be placed in some given definition files and I occasionally violates this rule. If such a way is available, then I can further examine them and easily extract those with non-English characters. The "locate" here means to output the positions in the console or a file, of course.

Certainly, the most obvious way is to find all double quotes in the given Lua file, but that will include string literals in comments, and it's also too brutal. So I wonder if there's some elegant way to achieve that? Many thanks!

Comment: Look at [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41381804/1847592)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `luac -p -l -l foo.lua`, which will list the constants used in foo.lua, including strings.

If you can use an external tool, try also my [ltokenp](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html#ltokenp), which uses the Lua lexer.

Here is a sample script to get you started. Save it as `strings.lua` and process your files with `ltokenp -s strings.lua foo.lua bar.lua`.

```
-- token filter: extract strings

local FILE

function FILTER(line,token,text,value)
    if text=="<file>" then
        FILE=value:sub(2)
    elseif text=="<string>" then
        print(FILE,line,string.format("%q",value))
    end
end
```